# Key in C# combobox but show different value

Tags: c#, combobox

I want to do a query on a database that will bring up a customerID (identity) and first and last name.

In the combobox I want to show first and last name but when selected - the value is the customerID. The customerID would run be the subject of another query to auto-populate a windows form.

This is what I have so far - I know the `combobox.Items.Add` part is wrong - that's where I'm having my issue.

```
conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "my connection string";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Customer", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
{
    comboSelectCust.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i]["FName" + "Surname"]);
}
```

Comment: In your case you wont get value. If I understood what you want then you need to know about `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties.

Answer (score 2):

Since you use a DataTable for this, why not just bind it with a DisplayMember and ValueMember?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the *Tag* property of *ComboBoxItem* to set the value (*Content* is the property that sets the display text):

```
comboSelectCust.Items.Add(new ComboBoxItem() { 
    Content = dt.Rows[i]["FName"] + dt.Rows[i]["Surname"], 
    Tag = dt.Rows[i]["customerId"]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
{
   comboSelectCust.Items.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, int>(dt.Rows[i]["FName"].ToString() +  dt.Rows[i]["Surname"].ToString(), Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["customerId"].ToString()));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is pseudo code how to use `DataSource`, `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select FName || Surename as FullName, customerID from Customer", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

comboSelectCust.DataSource = dt;
comboSelectCust.DisplayMember = "FullName";
comboSelectCust.ValueMember = "customerID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this an see

```
conn = new SqlConnection();
conn.ConnectionString = "my connection string";

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select (FName+' '+Surname) As Name,customerID from Customer", conn);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

da.Fill(dt);

comboSelectCust.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboSelectCust.ValueMember = "customerID";
comboSelectCust.DataSource = dt;
```

I changed the query and add display member and valuemeber properies and assign the data table as the data source